# Is there a way to add non-normal distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've looked around a bit and can't find a good answer to this question. Suppose I have two uniform variables on $[0,1]$, $X$ and $Y$. I know that averaging variables will tend to toward normality, but how about adding their probabilities together? So $P(x)$ on the distribution $X\&Y$ is defined by $P(x)$ on $X$ plus $P(x)$ on $Y$. I tried work it out generally for uniform variables but went entirely the wrong way and can't even begin to think about how to do it for general distributions $X,Y$. Is this a thing in probability, or is it not generally do-able for any distributions?

For clarity: What I mean is suppose you have some $x\in[0,1]$ and two probability distributions $X$ and $Y$ on $[0,1]$. If you define $X+Y$ as the distribution such that $P(x\in X+Y)=P(x\in X)+P(x\in Y)$, is there a good way to find that distribution if you know $X$ and $Y$? Not sure if that clarifies.

Comment: See [mixture distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures).

Comment: Are you looking for the probability of $X+Y$ or something else? It is not clear what you are asking!

Comment: You cannot add two probability distributions and get another probabilty distribution, since the integral of the sum over $\Bbb{R}$ is 2 rather than 1. However, you can average probability density functions to get a new PDF. In the case where the PDFs you're averaging are all the same this is not interesting, though.

Comment: For your example the distribution density of X+Y is a triangular distribution. Search for convolution of probability distributions to find out about the general case.